# Is there a way to select multiple input field types with CSS?

Tags: css, types, input, css-selectors

I have a text and a password input field that I'm trying to select in this fashion:

```
input[type=text][type=password]
```

however this does not work. I would refrain from using jQuery, so any help would be appreciated (without using custom classes).

Answer (score 80):

You need to specify the attributes separately, repeating the types if necessary and using comma(s):

```
input[type=text], input[type=password]
```

Your given selector is trying to match an `input` with a `type` that is both `text` and `password`, but a single element can't have different values for the same attribute so it fails.

Comment: @AnthonyAlmighty: Possibly because this was a drive-by question, and most users who post once and never come back don't realize that answers can be accepted - they post a question, get an answer, and that's it. Plus, this feature is unnecessarily hard to discover.

Comment: What if I wanted these to have a certain class?

Comment: Because he ONLY wants input password AND input text to match