# css grouping element under one class

Tags: css

Is there a way to group all the elements by referencing a class:

For example:

```
.formres select input[type="file"] input[type="email"] input[type="text"] input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
}
```

This is not working though, I want all the elements inside the class .formres to be width 150. Wondering if this is possible or if I have to write individual values.

PS

I already know about the comma way,

```
.formres select, .formres input[type="file"], .formres input[type="email"], .formres input[type="text"], .formres input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
}
```

some other way to do it, by some operator ? that does not require class name again and again.

Comment: re your additional question: As I wrote: Use SASS or LESS, but not with  CSS only.

Comment: If you want all the elements inside the class `.formres` to be `width: 150px`, then you can use `.formres * { width: 150px; }`. I'm not sure if that's actually what you want, though. Can you include your HTML, too? We need to see exactly which elements you want to select.

Comment: Likewise if you just want the inputs inside `.formres` to be width: 150px, then just use `.formres input { width:150px; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to select multiple input field types with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474057/is-there-a-way-to-select-multiple-input-field-types-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
.formres input[type="file"], .formres input[type="email"], .formres input[type="text"], .formres input[type="password"] {
    width: 150px;
}
```

ADDITION:

If you only have one or two input elements inside the DIV with that class which should NOT get the 150px width, you might use something like

```
.formres input {
  width: 150px;
}
.formres input[type="xxxx"] {
  width: auto;
}
```

The first will give all elements 150px width, the second will define/overwrite the one which doesn't get 150px, but the default `auto`.

Comment: Yea I already know it, but it needs the class name agian and again, I was confident that there must be a way or operator to achieve this but sadly I think this is the only way.

Comment: If you dont use any CSS preprocessor, this is the only way in this context.

Comment: Don't you think this is something really important, cause I only have four elements some website might have more than hundreds of element which needs to be referred with a class name...

Comment: then it's a good idea to use LESS or SASS - they are made exactly for this kind of stuff

Comment: Note: I added a possible solution to my answer which is shorter than the first one.

Comment: IMHO you should put that solution first.

Comment: @torazaburo It depends: I don't know how many input elements there are - if the majority of them *shouldn't* get the 150px, the first solution is better, since I would have to write more selectors for the second rule than in the first solution.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that the OP may not even know that he can simply say `input` and thinks he **has** to say `input[type=blah]`, perhaps based on some examples he saw, and may well want to apply the styling to **all** the input elements. Only way to know for sure is to ask him. But he did say *I want **all** the elements inside the class `.formres` to be width 150*.

Comment: ah - possibly true. I wouldn't have thought of that since the quoted code seemed very specific (i.e. unnecessaryly specific - not something you learn before you learn simple combined selectors).

Answer (score 1):

> I want all the elements inside the class `.formres` to be width 150.

I assume you mean all direct children.

> some other way to do it, by some operator ? that does not require class name again and again.

Yes, the operator you are looking for is the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors), the asterisk (`*`), which selects any element.

```
.formres > * { width: 150px; }
```

You might also consider using a container inside `.formres` with the desired width, and put the `input` elements inside that. They will expand to fill its width:

```
<form class="formres">
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text"...

.formres .container { width: 150px; }
```